# Why are deleted answers not counted on questions list, but counted on the question page?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

Almost everybody here know that 10k+ users can see deleted posts. For example when a question has deleted answers the total number of answers is counted on the question page (where the list of answers is displayed).

> [image]

But when you look at the same question from the questions list, the only non-deleted answers are counted:

> [image]

What is the reason to "hide" deleted answers from the question list, and only show them inside question itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you're looking for a question to answer. You see a question that you might want to answer, but it has 2 answers already, so you skip it.

If both of those answers were deleted, then the question is *unanswered*. And thus you could have gone in and provided an answer. So the question remains de-facto unanswered.

The information in the question list exists to serve the needs of people looking at and evaluating questions. The number of deleted answers to questions is useless to that evaluation and thus need not be provided.

Remember: the only reason 10k rep users can see deleted answers at all is so that they can evaluate them for possible undeletion. That's a moderation activity, not a normal SO usage activity.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is (probably) that the question lists are cached, and look the same for everybody, regardless of reputation. For users without 10k reputation (and visitors which are not logged in, who make up the majority of the traffic) it would be very confusing to count deleted answers here.

The question detail page on the other hand is generated on the fly. There it makes more sense to count the actual number of answers you can see.